# Как из числа сделать три числа внутри Select в Linq и добавить к каждому числу индекс?

Tags: c#, linq

На вход поступает строка, содержащая числа, разделенные запятой.

Из каждого числа n нужно получить три числа: n-1, n, n+1 . Кроме этого, к каждому из них записать индекс числа n.

Что получаем на вход:

```
1,2,3
```

Что должны получить на выход:

```
0 0
1 0
2 0
1 1
2 1
3 1
2 2
3 2
4 2
```

Смог только такую конструкции выстроить. Не понимаю каким образом преобразовать строку в число и сделать несколько математический операций n-1, n, n+1

```
public static void Main()
{
    string n = Console.ReadLine();
    var s = n.Split(",");
    var result = s.SelectMany((s1, index) => s1.Select(c => $"{c} {index}"));
    foreach (var x in result) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{x}");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Еще можно через массив чисел.

```
public class MainClass
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var numbers = Console.ReadLine().Split(',').Select(int.Parse);
            var result = numbers.SelectMany((n, index) => new [] { n - 1, n, n + 1 }
                                .Select(n => $"{n} {index}"));

       foreach (var item in result)
            { 
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
    }
}
```